# Templated Function results in Circular Inclusion

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a tricky circular inclusion issue that I dont know how to solve. To sum up:

> `IApp` inherits from `Component`
>   `Component` implements a templated function in its header file that uses `IApp::registerForEvent`

What technique or method can I use to fix/avoid this circular inclusion?

```
class Component;
class IApp;

class Component
{
    IApp* app;

    // Error: Invalid use of incomplete type 'class IApp'
    template<typename T>
    void registerEvent(const int& evtId, Status (T::*func) (int))
    {
        auto res = std::bind(func, (T*)this, std::placeholders::_1);
        app->registerForEvent(evtId);
    }
};

class IApp : public Component
{
public:
    void registerForEvent(const int& evtId)
    {
        printf("IApp::registerForEvent\n");

        // ... 
    }
};
```

Comment: You can compile if you use a forward declaration, but you fix the problem by asking "is `IApp` really a `Component`?"  "Can I break `IApp` into two classes:  a `Component` and a `ComponentRegistry`, perhaps?" ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LEomvWXOiI )

Comment: I suspect that `IApp` is both an interface and a singleton.  I would highly recommend rethinking that.  You don't get style points for using more patterns than the next guy ("One day I went to a brown bag lunch, and a lead architect proudly proclaimed that he had used every GoF Design Pattern in a project. What he failed to mention was that the software didn't live up to the customer's expectations. It didn't work." http://baus.net/doersandtalkers ; see also https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-singleton-detector/wikis/FAQ.wiki )

Answer (score 8):

Define registerEvent after IApp.

```
class IApp;

class Component
{
    IApp* app;
    template<typename T>
    void registerEvent(const int& evtId, Status (T::*func) (int));
};


class IApp : public Component {
  ...
};

template <typename T>
Component::registerEvent(const int& evtId, Status (T::*func) (int)) {
  auto res = std::bind(func, (T*)this, std::placeholders::_1);
  app->registerForEvent(evtId);
}
```

If need be, also define `A::registerEvent` after `Component::registerEvent`.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use a derived class in it's base class, which doesn't seem like a good design approach to me. I would suggest moving it to some other class, which both classes have access to.

Answer (score 2):

Your are aggregating a Derived class object. Your may thus solve the circular dependence with the curiously recurring template pattern?

```
template <typename Aggregated>
class Component
{
    Aggregated* app;

    template<typename T>
    void registerEvent(const int& evtId, Status (T::*func) (int))
    {
        auto res = std::bind(func, (T*)this, std::placeholders::_1);
        app->registerForEvent(evtId);
    }
};

class IApp : public Component<IApp>
{
public:
    void registerForEvent(const int& evtId)
    {
        printf("IApp::registerForEvent\n");

        // ...
    }
};
```

Still, it is not clear to me what you are trying to do. For one you assume the function passed Component::registerEvent is a member of Component (you bind to (T*)this) whilst delegating the Event ID to the aggregated IApp. To me it seems rethinking your design may solve also the circular dependence problem?